# asp.net core Docker Image for ARMv8

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, armv8

I am looking for a for asp.net core sdk and runtime docker image for ARMv8 but so far I scoured the docker hub repos and I could only see ARM32.
What does this mean? do I have to create my own image?
Or do I have to use the ARM32 on the ARMv8 Architecture?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/480 and maybe create an issue in that repo.